# how to pass large amount of data when exporting to excel using angularjs and web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using angularjs + web api for my website.
I need to export a table to excel. I tried to use different JS methods, it worked on chrome but I also need it to work on >IE8.

So, I decided to use the server: send my table's $scope.data to server using post.
this is how it looks:

```
    function excel_service($http) {
    var _$http = $http;
    self = this;
    self.ExportToExcel = function (excel_data) {
        var promise = _$http({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'api/ExportToExcel',
            data: { "ExcelData": excel_data }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
        return promise;
    };
};
```

when I debug, I see that part of the data appears in the request, but then, there is an error...
I think it's because I am trying to pass about 700 rows using that method.

Is there a way to send large data via post, or perhaps my approach is wrong, and It's better if I saved the data in server's session when it was retrieved, and then export it to excel from there.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @s83, I have fallen same problem. Have you gotten your solution.

Comment: Hi, you can try to send the great ammount of data by 'bulks'. each time 100 records or something. of course in the end you will have to check that all the data have been transeferd